# Avr assembly programming: atomic allocation on the stack

Tags: assembly, interrupt, avr

I'm looking at the `avr-gcc` assembly generated code for small C programs. The following is supposed to allocate a 100 byte local array on the stack.

```
extern void foo(char [], int);

void bar()
{
  char t[100];
  foo(t,100);
}
```

and of course it does, by subtracting 100 from the stack pointer.

I understand that, as the avr is a 8 bit machine, changing the 16bit stack pointer takes 2 steps (changing SPH and SPL). Also, it is a good idea to provide some atomicity by disabling interrupts. It is done by the sequence

```
in r28,__SP_L__
in r29,__SP_H__           ; get SP
subi r28,100              ; new SP in R29:R28 = OLD -100 
sbc r29,__zero_reg__
in __tmp_reg__,__SREG__   ; save status to r0
cli                       ; disable interrupts
out __SP_H__,r29          ; update SPH
out __SREG__,__tmp_reg__  ; restore status   -- why here ?
out __SP_L__,r28          ; update SPL
```

what I'm not convinced yet is the position of the restore status instruction.

Why is it *not* done after updating SPL ?

Maybe there is a guarantee that after (re)enabling interrupts, no interrupt will be taken into accounts before the next instruction has completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your are right.
I cannot find a definitive source and neither can the guys at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209581/avr-sei-instruction) apparently<sup>1</sup>.

The closest we got is this statement from the [AVR ISA manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf) for the `sei` instruction:

> Sets the Global Interrupt Flag (I) in SREG (Status Register). The instruction following SEI will be executed before any pending interrupts.

Now, as questioned in the EE site, this may be a feature of the `sei` instruction itself or it maybe a feature of the architecture itself<sup>2</sup>.

If you look at the opcodes `sei` is actually just `bset 7` but no note about pending interrupts is present in the `bset` page, despite `bset 7` acting just like `sei`.
So I believe that setting the *I-bit* in *SREG* will mask interrupt for one more instruction, whenever you use `out` or `sei`.

More information on the linked question: [AVR sei instruction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209581/avr-sei-instruction)<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> The question linked is identical to your, it contain actual answers not like this fake one.
<sup>2</sup> i.e. it doesn't count how you change `SREG`.
<sup>3</sup> Re-linked.